# Gxt ListView problems with items - doesn't catch image by img src in html code

Tags: html, listview

Friends, I've got code from sencha examples from here http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:listview

changed parameters for html

```
    
    {photo.name:shorten(18)}
```

but my image after compiling in IntelliJ Idea is not been caught in the listview (there is red X in the corner)

I really don't understand, please help me.

My Java code is

```
ListViewCustomAppearance<InfoPerimetr> appearance = new ListViewCustomAppearance<InfoPerimetr>("." + style.thumbWrap(),
                    style.over(), style.select()) {
                @Override
                public void renderEnd(SafeHtmlBuilder builder) {
                    String markup = new StringBuilder("<div class=\"").append(CommonStyles.get().clear()).append("\"></div>").toString();
                    builder.appendHtmlConstant(markup);
                }

                @Override
                public void renderItem(SafeHtmlBuilder builder, SafeHtml content) {
                    builder.appendHtmlConstant("<div class='" + style.thumbWrap() + "' style='border: 1px solid white'>");
                    builder.append(content);
                    builder.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
                }
            };

            ListView<InfoPerimetr, InfoPerimetr> listView = new ListView<InfoPerimetr, InfoPerimetr>(store, new IdentityValueProvider<InfoPerimetr>() {
                @Override
                public void setValue(InfoPerimetr object, InfoPerimetr value) {
                }

            }, appearance);
            listView.setCell(/*new IconCellDecorator<String>(AppBundle.IMAGE.userIcon16(), new ImageCell()*/
            new SimpleSafeHtmlCell<InfoPerimetr>(new AbstractSafeHtmlRenderer<InfoPerimetr>() {
                @Override
                public SafeHtml render(InfoPerimetr object) {
                    //ZSafeUri path = new ZSafeUri(object.getPath());
                  //  object.setPath(Images.INSTANCE.image1().getSafeUri().asString());
                    return renderer.renderItem(object, style);
                }
            }));
            listView.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler<InfoPerimetr>() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<InfoPerimetr> event) {
                    panel.setHeadingText("Simple ListView (" + event.getSelection().size() + " items selected)");
                }
            });
            listView.setBorders(false);</i>
```

Comment: <html>
<body>
<div class="{style.thumb}"><img
        src = "thumbs/Screenshot.jpg"
           title="{photo.name}"></div>
<span class="x-editable">{photo.name:shorten(18)}</span>
</body>
</html>

this is my html code

Comment: When I add so: "file://D:/project/myproj/src/com/grand/gpix/client/module/ipr/ViewPanel/ScreenShots/CarouselTest/images/Screenshot.bmp"; in html code, it works, but when i try put in html code variable ({photo.path}) and accept that value in java code, it converts to "#"